# Paper revision exact deadline

Tags: publications, deadlines

I am revising a paper submitted to IEEE TVT journal. I'm quite tight on time and trying to complete the paper revision by its deadline which is on Sep 10,2018 (Monday).

Does anyone have a paper on TVT and know the exact meaning of deadline for this journal ? Is it on Sunday night or Monday night ?

Comment: There was a downvote. I upvoted to make it up. I suspect it's because of the acronym TVT. Did you mean  IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology by IEEE TVT? Please clarify.

Comment: **Ask the editor.**

Comment: Since this is already the date in question, let me note that the mail you got on the deadline may be very specific (date, time, place) or not. If not you can _probably_ interpret it liberally in case you can't reach the editor in question. If they say 11:59PM EDT, Sept 9... then they probably mean it literally. But they may otherwise be interpreting it as local time on the 10th. That is most likely the case unless it was _very_ specific.

Answer (score 8):

**Relax**. Journal deadlines [are not strict](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49109/how-strict-are-paper-revision-deadlines) (unless they are for special issues with a set publication date). They're more intended to help keep the journal organized. Chances are you can go weeks past the deadline and nothing will happen, although if you wait months, your submission might be removed as dormant.

If you're still concerned, ask for a deadline extension. It's likely the journal will grant it.

Comment: While this may be completely true _in general_ it may also be unwise to depend on the advice given in the first paragraph here. "Chances are" won't help you if you are rejected even if other journals wouldn't do that. Meet the deadline or ask the editor. Yes, if you request an extension it will _likely_ be granted, but not if you don't ask. Assumptions are less than safe.

Answer (score 0):

While a journal editor is unlikely to completely reject your paper for missing a deadline, there are things you should consider. The first is that you should keep the editor informed if you will miss a deadline, ask for an extension, and provide a realistic estimate for completion.

One reason for providing a deadline is just to keep you working. But note that an editor will typically have several issues in preparation at the same time. There may be restrictions on total length of an issue, both minimum and maximum, and the editor may already have a slot in mind for your paper, provided that you complete in time to fit the production schedule.

If you miss the deadline, then, while the paper may still be accepted, it may be delayed in publication, possibly for quite a while. That might be especially true for a long paper.

Of course, if there is no *physical* version of the publication and everything is done online, then the length is less of an issue. However, the editor may also have an idea about a *theme* for each issue and your paper may fit that theme for an upcoming issue. If you miss deadlines then it may take even longer, until that theme comes up again or a more general issue is created.

It is to your advantage, in just about every way, to work with the editor to make his/her life easier. It is a mutual thing. In particular, don't make assumptions that, if incorrect, make life difficult for both you and the editor. It is easy enough in most cases to find out what you need to know.